# Are Message Queues the right tool for geographically distributed deployments?

Tags: synchronization, message-queue, amqp

Our scenario is as follows (which I guess is not unique): we have our database backed web apps in two different colocation facilities. One facility has the master database, the other one has the slave.

We want the slave facility to keep working (in limited mode if necessary) even if the master database is offline. When the master database comes backup, the data should get synchronized.

I was thinking that I can use messages queues to send the data update instructions. The message queue in the slave server will hold its messages if there is a disconnect between the slave and master servers. When the connection comes back up the messages will flow and the master server will update the database.

Am I missing something? Is this not a good use for message queues?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, however it is not as straightforward as using message queues in the data centre. You may need to set up an architecture with bridging between two persistent message clusters. One way to do this is to set up a RabbitMQ broker (or broker cluster) in each physical location and then bridge those locations using another protocol such as is done with this ZeroMQ plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rmq-0mq/wiki

The end result is a federation of message brokers. Depending on the volume of data and the distance between locations you may want to build compression into the architecture either with a compressed VPN link for bridging or some kind of batching and compression between the clusters.

But that is not the only way to do this. Another way is to have one central RabbitMQ cluster and to use SSL client connections to this cluster over the Internet. If the locations are relatively close together, this would be a better solution. For instance if all locations were in the Northeastern USA, this is the way that I would do it. But if the locations are in the USA, Europe and Asia, then it would be better to use the federated solution to bridge data between clusters of brokers.

And in a really big organization, say 100 locations across three continents, you would probably want to combine the two solutions.

But if this is really just as simple as two locations with a master db and a replica, I think you are better off sticking with the standard db replication solutions, and consider supplementing that with a compressed link between them if the volume of data is really big. The replication solutions that I am aware of already handle saving updates to send later, when the link between master and slave goes down. Best forget about AMQP in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

IBM DB2 has a facility called `"Q Replication"` for replicating committed transactional data from DB2(R) UDB sources to targets. The Q Replication uses `WebSphere MQ` queues and two programs `Q Capture` and `Q Apply` to replicate the data. The `Q Capture` program runs on the source, captures the data and sends to WebSphere MQ queues. The Q Apply program runs on target, receives messages from WebSphere MQ queue and applies the data to the target database.

You can find more information on Q Replication [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.ii.doc/start/cgpch300.htm)